iOS の safari や chrome で position: sticky かつ writing-mode: vertical-rl のコンテンツが断続的に消える
iOS で position:sticky と writing-mode:vertical-rl を組み合わせて使用すると、position:sticky を指定した要素内のコンテンツが、ページが読み込まれたとき、あるいは縦方向にちょこっとスクロールしたときに、表示が消えることがあります。
DEMO on Netlify
コンテンツを右から左に読むようにして、各セクションの見出し部を position:sticky にしたいというのが求める挙動なのですが、この問題を回避する方法、または代替案はありますでしょうか。。。
■確認したiOSのバージョン
iOS 15.8.3 / 16.7.8 / 17.6.1
■ブラウザ
safari / Google chrome
■再現手順

ページを読み込む。
ページを上下にスクロールする。
sticky要素内のコンテンツが消えたり現れたりする。

■試したこと

.stickyに以下のCSSを追加

-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden；
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)；
will-change: transform；


htmlとbodyに以下のCSSを追加

overscroll-behavior: none；



.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.group {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    right: 0;
}

/* 見栄えのための設定 */
.sticky {
    background: #3ea4b8;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
li {
    padding: 1em;
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="group">
        <h2 class="sticky">Fruits</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Apple harvest has begun</li>
            <li>A new variety of grapes has been introduced</li>
            <li>Orange imports are increasing</li>
            <li>The nutritional value of bananas is being reassessed</li>
            <li>The mango season has arrived</li>
            <li>Cherry prices are rising</li>
            <li>The health benefits of pineapples</li>
            <li>How to chill watermelon</li>
            <li>New melon recipes</li>
            <li>Strawberry storage methods</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <h2 class="sticky">Vegetables</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Tomato cultivation techniques are evolving</li>
            <li>A new variety of cucumbers is gaining attention</li>
            <li>The health benefits of cabbage are being reassessed</li>
            <li>How to keep lettuce fresh</li>
            <li>The nutritional value of carrots has improved</li>
            <li>Broccoli cooking methods</li>
            <li>Spinach storage methods</li>
            <li>A bountiful potato harvest</li>
            <li>Eggplant popularity is surging</li>
            <li>Bell pepper cooking ideas</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <h2 class="sticky">Meat</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Beef consumption is increasing</li>
            <li>New cooking methods for pork</li>
            <li>Chicken prices are stable</li>
            <li>Lamb popularity is rising</li>
            <li>The health impacts of bacon</li>
            <li>Ham storage methods</li>
            <li>New sausage recipes</li>
            <li>The nutritional value of duck meat</li>
            <li>Turkey cooking methods</li>
            <li>The supply of venison is increasing</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <h2 class="sticky">Fish</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Salmon farming techniques are improving</li>
            <li>Tuna catch volumes are increasing</li>
            <li>Cod cooking methods are gaining attention</li>
            <li>Squid consumption is surging</li>
            <li>The health benefits of shrimp</li>
            <li>Crab market prices are stable</li>
            <li>Mackerel storage methods</li>
            <li>The high nutritional value of flounder</li>
            <li>New mackerel cooking ideas</li>
            <li>Sardine catch volumes are increasing</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>



